# CMS blocks in outside script

Tags: magento2, php

I'm looking for a solution to retrieve a few `cms` blocks outside the Magento2 installation.

The script will be on the same server so I'm able to load the `bootstrap.php` file. Actually I've found a solution to get the cart content but unfortunately I didn't found any solution for retrieving blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Put your script into `pub` folder and then give bootstrap path like below:

```
// MAGENTO START
    include('../../app/bootstrap.php');

    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
```

Now you can get CMS page using objectmanager.

Comment: That I've already achieved, however my question is how i can call for a block element.

Comment: you can show me your code here.

Answer (score 0):

Script is neither the recommended nor the easy method of doing this. You should better use Magento APIs for getting magento data outside of magento.
You can do this using **cmsBlockRepositoryV1** APIs.
If you have to just retrieve blocks you can use GET `/V1/cmsBlock/{blockId}` 
For more info go to following link - 
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/